# Pester mock method for Powershell 5 class

Tags: class, powershell, pester

I am having an issue trying to mock a powershell 5 class method, when executing the test, I get the error " CommandNotFoundException: Could not find Command FunctionToMock". I am trying to unit test the "OutputToOverwrite" method by mocking "FunctionToMock". I think I would have to mock ChocoClass itself first, but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks.

```
Class ChocoClass
{
    [string] OutputToOverwrite()
    {
        return $this.FunctionToMock()
    }

    [string] FunctionToMock()
    {
        return "This text will be replaced"
    }
}


Describe "Testing mocking"{
    it "Mock test"{
        Mock FunctionToMock -MockWith {return "mystring"}
        $package = New-Object ChocoClass
        $expected = $package.OutputToOverwrite()
        $expected | should BeExactly "mystring"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen two ways to do this:

1. Separate the bulk of the implementation into a function.
2. Inherit from the class and override the method.

### (1) Use a Function

I have been separating the implementation of methods into functions like this:

```
Class ChocoClass
{
    [string] OutputToOverwrite()
    {
        return $this.FunctionToMock()
    }

    [string] FunctionToMock()
    {
        return FunctionToMock $this
    }
}

function FunctionToMock
{
    param($Object)
    return "This text will be replaced"
}
```

With that change, your test passes on my computer.  This avoids PowerShell-class-related pitfalls but also avoids testing class behavior.

### (2) Derive and Override the Method

You can derive the class and override the method you want to mock:

```
Describe "Testing mocking"{
    it "Mock test"{
        class Mock : ChocoClass {
            [string] FunctionToMock() { return "mystring" }
        }
        $package = New-Object Mock
        $expected = $package.OutputToOverwrite()
        $expected | should BeExactly "mystring"
    }
}
```

This test passes on my computer.  I haven't used this method for production code yet, but I like how direct it is.  Watch out for problems related to re-defining classes with the same name in a single PowerShell session (see side note below).

---

*Side note: The separation of (1) minimizes the amount I run into [this bug that prevents classes from being reloaded when you make changes to them](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2505#issuecomment-263157383).  I have found, though, that the better workaround is to invoke each test run in a new PowerShell session (e.g. `PS C:\>powershell.exe -Command { Invoke-Pester }`) so I'm leaning toward (2) now.*

Comment: Yes I thought about that solution, which works, but I would have to create a lot of functions to tests my class methods. Oh thanks for the side note, I thought I was doing something wrong or going crazy.

Comment: I've heard from (or was warned by) more than one PowerShell MVP that PowerShell classes were created to support class-based DSC resources.  Using PowerShell classes otherwise means you will encounter rough edges because that use hasn't been a priority for the PowerShell team to support.  I'm using PowerShell classes for OOP, but in my first such project I had to write about 10x as much test code than production code around classes to figure out how things behaved.

Comment: Many of those tests I published [here](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/tree/master/EnvironmentTests).  Look for the test files mentioning "class", "using", and "IEnumerable".  I'll add a stackoverflow.com filter for PowerShell class questions so I see yours if you run into more rough edges.

Comment: @BenoitM I added another way to do this that _I think_ is closer to what you were hoping for.

Comment: I am testing the usage of classes to simplify reusability of functions/library in scripts and manage the scope. I don't think I will need much of OOP. I really like solution(2). I will try in a complex class to see if it adds to much bloat in the test script, but it looks like it shouldn't.