# Mocking class functions with Pester 5 and PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, pester

Does anyone have an example of mocking a dot-sourced class function with Pester 5 and PowerShell 7?

Thank you.

**Edit: example**

Classes\MyClass.ps1:

```
class MyClass {
    [void] Run() {
        Write-Host "Class: Invoking run..."
    }
}
```

MyModule.psm1:

```
# Import classes
. '.\Classes\MyClass.ps1'

# Instantiate classes
$MyClass = [MyClass]::new()

# Call class function
$MyClass.Run()
```

Comment: Yeah, [the docs have plenty](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Mock). Anything _specific_ that you're struggling with?

Comment: Hey, yeah - I can mock most things without problem.  It's specifically functions defined in a class.

Comment: Functions defined in a class method are still just functions. Are you trying to mock a class _method_?

Comment: Yeah, correct. My bad on the wording.  Provided an example in the original q.

Comment: No worries, the example makes it clear :)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513644/pester-mock-method-for-powershell-5-class

Comment: I'll give those a go, the solutions look a bit messy - will get back to you briefly.

Comment: I tried both, first option would work but is messy with multiple methods to mock. Second is similar to the answer from @MathiasR.Jessen which I'll reply to separately.

Answer (score 2):

Pester only mocks *commands* - not classes or their methods.

The easiest way to "mock" a PowerShell class for method dispatch testing is by taking advantage of the fact that PowerShell marks all methods `virtual`, thereby allowing derived classes to override them:

```
class MockedClass : MyClass
{
  Run() { Write-host "Invoking mocked Run()"}
}
```

---

The nice thing about this approach is that functions that constrain input to the `MyClass` type will still work with the mocked type:

```
function Invoke-Run
{
  param([MyClass]$Instance)

  $instance.Run()
}

$mocked = [MockedClass]::new()
Invoke-Run -Instance $mocked    # this still works because [MockedClass] derives from [MyClass]
```

Comment: How are you letting Pester know what MyClass is? `class MockedClass : MyClass`.  Right now Pester is returning `Unable to find type [MyClass]`.

Comment: @XeonFibre either add a `using module ModuleContainingClassDef` directive to the test script file, or define the class inline with `Invoke-Expression` (ie. `iex 'class MockedClass : ...'`)

Comment: Any chance you'd know how to use Mock ... -Verifiable with your solution?  Then I could ensure the mocked method is called.

Comment: I didn't have much luck but it's alright, I'm going to create some interfaces and go that route instead.  It'll enable me to validate the functions are being called correctly and the tests should be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have an example of mocking a dot-sourced class function
> with Pester 5 and PowerShell 7?

You can look at this repo:
https://github.com/dsccommunity/SqlServerDsc/blob/8dde54df19ccbdb95629ec1c074e7a97acf229d2/tests/Unit/Classes/ResourceBase.Tests.ps1#L111-L165

Also, see my answer here which contains example code:
["Unable to find type" when mocking class in a Powershell unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275024/unable-to-find-type-when-mocking-class-in-a-powershell-unit-test)